# How can I run my *.pro file with QtCreator?

Tags: qt-creator, qmake, .profile

All.
I just setup Ubuntu 14.04 and installed QT5.4 using command below. (VMware)

```
$ wget http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.4/5.4.0-rc/qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.0-rc.run
$ chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.0-rc.run
$ ./qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.0-rc.run
```

QtCreator could be installed in this step.

**BUT** I cannot execute `*.pro` file for my Qt Project. 
Type of this is `'plain text document (text/plain)'` and executed by gedit.
So I tried to change application for executing QtCreator there aren't in the Application List.

I am executing QtCreator by running qtcreator file in `'/home/XXX/Qt5.4.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/'`.
In addition, when I find QtCreator in Ubuntu SW center, QtCreator is not installed.

Must I install QtCreator and apply QT5.4 kit again?
Or Can I execute *.pro by my current QtCreator?

I am not a native English speaker so I am sorry for my bad English.
I couldn't find any information about my problem using my language.

PS) I prepared image to understand my problem, I can not post it because I don't have 10 reputation.... sorry.

Thanks,
Honken

Answer (score 3):

You don't execute `*.pro` files with QtCreator. `*.pro` files are to be executed using **qmake** in console ex.

```
$ qmake yourProject.pro
```

For more infomation see [Qmake Tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-tutorial.html)

If you want to use QtCreator to build your project, you have to:

1. Start *QtCreator*
2. Select **File -> Open project**
3. Choose your `*.pro` file from the disk.
4. Select **Build -> Run qmake**